# How to trace/monitor the I/O of a Linux command

Tags: command-line, disk, debugging, io

I ran `find / -name abc.html` and a short time after I ran this command again. This time it was very fast, so I know the `find` must be caching the result somewhere.

How can I find out where the cache is stored?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, as @zongfu pointed out, `find` does not cache its results in a file, but rather the kernel is caching the directories `find` is reading so they can be read again without touching the disk, which is why it is faster.  If you still want to see what kind of IO a program is doing though, you can use `strace`.  This program runs another program you specify and logs the system calls the program makes.  Without any arguments it will print them all, which can be a lot of information, so you man want to limit it to only certain calls, such as `open()` so you can see what files the program is going to open.  This would look like:

```
strace -eopen someprogram
```

Answer (score 5):

`find` does not cache anything, especially onto disk. The reason why the second run is a lot faster is because the Linux caches the accessed data (in this case directory listings) in memory (see `free`).